# Table design advice

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table users:

```
user_id - name
```

And those users can create an article and then share it with other members, table articles:

```
article_id - user_id - article_name
```

The question is the best way to share it... I'm thinking another table article_shares:

```
share_id - article_id - user_id
```

This would simply list all users with access to that aerticle and the creator would have access to be able to add or delete from that table for the article they created

So, when the article creator (user_id 123) looks at his articles he can see a list of all other users he has shared each article with

```
select as.user_id, a.article_name from article_shares as
join users u on u.user_id = as.user_id
join articles a on a.article_id = as.article_id where u.user_id = '123'
```

and a user (user_id 456) can see a list of articles they have been shared

```
select a.article_name from articles a
join article_shares as on as.article_id = a.article_id
where as.user_id = '456'
```

Does this seem logical? Am I on the right track?

Thanks for any help

Comment: yep looks ok to me. You need some way to relate shared articles to users who can see them, I can't think of an easier way.

Comment: @Jay Thanks, only taught myself about joins two days ago so thanks for taking the time to have a look!

Comment: You're on the right track. Once you get comfortable with using JOIN, and all it's forms (INNER, LEFT etc) you may feel that there's nothing you can't do! :)

Comment: The only question I have is why do you need share_id in article_shares.

Comment: @MaxVT I always create an id for any table I create - just habit I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it right.  If you're curious, you've made a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) to create your many-to-many relationship between `users` and `articles`, and this is fairly standard.

You'll often see these types of tables named like `ArticlesToUsers` or something similar, and that will sometimes be the first way to tip you off that you're looking at a junction table.  Of course, naming schemes are pretty subjective, so don't feel the need to change the name.  `article_shares` seems like a good description to me.

As @MaxVT has demonstrated, you'll find that many developers won't put a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) on a junction table like this, and would rather just use both columns as the primary key (article_id, user_id).  The choice is obviously yours and may have more to do with staying consistent with the rest of the database tables, though you'll certainly see all permutations in the wild.  In the event that you do keep your surrogate key, I'd recommend a unique constraint of `article_id, user_id` anyway to eliminate duplicates (why would an article need to be shared to a user twice?).

Comment: Thanks Tim, appreciate that advice!